# How do you get bit_length() in PARI/GP

Tags: pari, pari-gp

I've looked on google and couldn't find the answer and thought i'd ask PARI/GP users here. My question is simply How do you get bit_length() in PARI/GP, that you can use at there interpreter here: https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For integers, it is just `bit_length(n) = #binary(n);`. For example:

```
bit_length(n) = #binary(n);
bit_length(100)
> 7
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably the fastest way (for positive integers) is

```
len(n)=exponent(n)+1
```

Answer (score 1):

Faster for large numbers than `binary` is just to use `logint` (requires `n > 0`).

```
1 + logint(n,2)
```